# SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: reqxp

Tags: javascript, sqlite

So I am trying to round a number in a cell for the last hour but can not figure it out.

`` db.run(`SELECT round(reqxp) WHERE userid = ?`, [userid]) ``

This is what I got so far.

And now I am getting an error

`SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: reqxp`

but if you look at my table that exists there.

Also I have tried this

`` db.run(`SELECT userstats round(reqxp) WHERE userid = ?`, [userid]) ``
But 0 success!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you forgot to specify the table from which to select:

```
db.run(`SELECT round(reqxp) FROM your_table_goes_here WHERE userid = ?`, [userid])
```

https://tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_select_query.htm